# Fullcalender - multiple calls are made when clicked on prev and next button

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When clicked on nextor previous button it makes multiple calls , As many time I click on these buttons those many time the cal is made . Below is the code

```
    var sourceFullView = "@Url.Action("GetDiaryEvents","LeaveCalender")";
    var sourceSummaryView="@Url.Action("GetDiarySummary","LeaveCalender")";
    var CalLoading = true;$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        events:"@Url.Action("GetDiaryEvents","LeaveCalender")",

        viewRender: function (view, element) {

            if (!CalLoading) {
                if (view.name == 'month') {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                }
                else {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    CalLoading = false;


});
```

Please someone help me find solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved this problem by below solution. I was using FullCalendar v2.1.1 There is a bug in lib , source is not cleared , it keeps on growing on every click because of which multiple calls are made . As a solution replace removeEventSource(source) with below code

```
function removeEventSource(source) {
sources = $.grep(sources, function(src) {
    return !isSourcesEqual(src, source);
});
// remove all client events from that source
sources = [];  // this is a bug fix , clear source
cache = $.grep(cache, function(e) {
    return !isSourcesEqual(e.source, source);
});
reportEvents(cache);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/), about viewRender:

> This callback will get triggered when the user changes the view, or
>   when any of the date navigation methods are called.

So you are removing and adding all the events in every change of the view, including clicking prev/next buttons.

Usually, your sources are just add once at the beginning, when you init the calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     eventSources: [
        sourceFullView,
        sourceSummaryView
    ]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
                alert(CalLoading);
                if (!CalLoading) {

                    if (view.name == "month") {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
                    }
                    CalLoading = true;  // <<<<--- Cambialo Así ;)
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should add some explanation. Code-only answer are not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `all event sources`.

replace `removeEventSource` by `removeEventSources` and `sourceFullView` by `null`

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
```

replace above line by

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources', null);
```